# Getting absolute location of a fragment in an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an activity with a couple of fragments inside. I'm using Frame Layout for each of the fragment and have Relative Layout as parent.

I've been having headaches on getting the exact location of a fragment in parent. But seems like I am only able to relative values.

So, is there anyway to get an exact location of a fragment within an activity?

Comment: Why would you need this information? Absolute positioning is to be avoided on Android.

Comment: I'd like to use it with an Animator

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this with Fragments but with the contents of fragments. 
If you use `findById()` on the activity that will find the id of anything inflated in that activity (including fragment contents etc).

You can then use something like [View.getLocationOnScreen(int[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29) this should give you the x and y of the View on screen. Never tried this on a fragment, but if you fragment is wrapped by a Layout then should be no problem.

Hope this helps?

Actually this might help, might need changing to take in two views as this method is inside a custom RelativeLayout I made:

```
/**
 * Will return the X,Y of the Anchor view relative to this relative layout.. So It doesn't
 * matter if the anchor view is nested, or any any other layout, this WILL find its location
 * relative too this {@link HelpRelativeLayout}.
 * 
 * @author chris.jenkins
 * @param anchor
 * @return
 */
private int[] calculateAnchorViewPosition(View anchor)
{
    int[] loc = new int[2];
    int[] conLoc = new int[2];
    // getLocationInWindow(conLoc);
    getLocationOnScreen(conLoc);
    // anchor.getLocationInWindow(loc);
    anchor.getLocationOnScreen(loc);

    // get correct top left pos + half the h/w of the anchor
    loc[0] = (loc[0] - conLoc[0]);
    loc[1] = (loc[1] - conLoc[1]);

    MyLog.d(loc[0] + " " + loc[1]);

    return loc;
}
```